# iPhone effect hide slow object

Tags: iphone, object, slider, hide, uislider

i've a problem : in my app i've a UISlider. Its function is to set the volume of some files i've included. I want to do this thing : the slider will be hide when user tap the screen and will be not hide when the user retap the screen. But there were 2 problems : 
1.- i want to use a slow hide effect, not from .alpha=0.0 to .alpha=1.0, but gradually
2.- i don't know what to do if user tap the screen when slider is going to hide or to show

Sorry for my english, i'm italian :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use animations

// To hide the slider slowly

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
slider.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

// To show the slider

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
slider.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: thnx. If you got any answers pls click on the up arrow and the tick mark which indicates u have accepted the answer. The more answers u accept the more replies u get for ur queries. Happy coding :)